# Django Rest Framework how to serialize a relational Model?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am learning Django Rest Framework and creating some APIs with success. Now I am trying to serialize a relation, but I don't know how this works. Here is my code:

```
class Countries(models.Model):
    country = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'countries'

class Users(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Countries, models.DO_NOTHING)
    date = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'users'
```

In views.py

```
def get(self,request):
        print(UsersSerializer)
        users = Users.objects.all()
        serializer = UsersSerializer(users,many = True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Serializer:

```
class UsersSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Users
        fields = '__all__'
```

When I run the API I am getting

```
[
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "dsadasd",
    "email": "dasd@gmail.com",
    "date": "2020-05-12T12:15:24Z",
    "country": 1
  }
]
```

In the country field I am getting country `id` and I was expecting the country name here...

Comment: Try use `source` attribute on `UsersSerializer` like described https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source so defining attribute like `country = serializers.CharField(source='country.name')` should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`source`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source) field argument to retrieve the `country` instead of the `id`:

> ... or may use dotted notation to traverse attributes, such as `EmailField(source='user.email')`. When serializing fields with dotted notation, **it may be necessary to provide a default value if any object is not present or is empty during attribute traversal.**

Therefore your serializer should look like this:

```
class UsersSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    country = serializers.CharField(source='country.country', default='')

    class Meta:
        model = Users
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'email', 'date', 'country')
        # You may use fields='__all__' but I find the explicit declaration 
        # more flexible.
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to change your `UsersSerializer` to return country name insread of id.

```
class UsersSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    country = serializers.SerializerMethodField()  # add this line

    class Meta:
        model = Users
        fields = '__all__'

    def get_country(self, instance):
        return instance.country.country  # return country name
```

Further read [SerializerMethodField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield).

Comment: This is a valid solution as well. Just keep in mind that the `source` passes through the chosen field's validation methods but you have to provide your validation (if it is needed) to the `SrializerMethodField`'s method. +1 from me :) !

Comment: @JohnMoutafis I didn't know about source field validation process, thanks for providing valuable info.